# Magento Template is not Loading

Tags: php, magento

I need to remove default Magento checkout and add custom one.Problem is Custom extension template is not loading.Log doesn't show any errors.I have attached screenshot http://skit.ch/nwpi

Code is here https://gist.github.com/3636029

Two questions here,

Blocks are not rendering?

Even though I've unset `"checkout.onepage"` block,when I dump entire layout,it shows the default checkout layout code.Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Stupid question: is your module enabled?

Comment: Where exactly the layout file onepagecheckout.xml is placed? Can you show the file path?

Comment: @blakcaps thanks! What happens if you change in onepagecheckout.xml the handler <checkout_onepage_index> to <onepagecheckout_onepage_index> ?

Comment: @ceckoslab Adding <onepagecheckout_onepage_index> didn't work.System generated handle is <checkout_onepage_index> but the expected is <onepagecheckout_onepage_index>.I guess module xml file is not loading.

Comment: I just looked at the provided code snippets. My first thought is that rewrite directive is not applied. Just in case do you have file: app/etc/modules/Namespace_Onepagecheckout.xml and is it populated with the right XML directives, like code poll and active state?

Comment: Yes.Module registration file present and its correct

Comment: @ceckoslab Problem is with removing existing blocks.Below is the answer.I appreciate your suggestions as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your controller:

`$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->unsetChildren('checkout.onepage');`

See:

```
Mage_Core_Block_Abstract

/**
 * Unset all children blocks
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
 */
public function unsetChildren()
{
    $this->_children       = array();
    $this->_sortedChildren = array();
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Unset child block
 *
 * @param  string $alias
 * @return Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
 */
public function unsetChild($alias)
{
    if (isset($this->_children[$alias])) {
        unset($this->_children[$alias]);
    }

    if (!empty($this->_sortedChildren)) {
        $key = array_search($alias, $this->_sortedChildren);
        if ($key !== false) {
            unset($this->_sortedChildren[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So your code should be, either:

`$this->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout.onepage')->unsetChildren();`

**OR**

`$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->unsetChild('checkout.onepage');`